# Postgres refresh materialized view doesn't persist new data

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function that refreshes a Postgres view. The data appears to refresh for the current connection, but does not persist for future connections.

```
kwargs = { 'async': 0 }
conn = extensions.connection(dsn, **kwargs)
cur.execute("select max(updated_at), count(*) from my_view; ")
last_updated = cur.fetchone()
print("LambdaRefreshView: Starting to refresh, last updated {}".format(last_updated))
cur.execute("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view;")
cur.execute("select max(updated_at), count(*) from my_view; ")
last_updated = cur.fetchone()
print("LambdaRefreshView: Finished refreshing, last updated {}".format(last_updated))
```

outputs:

```
LambdaRefreshView: Starting to refresh, last updated (2021-09-24 21:31:46, 299906)
LambdaRefreshView: Finished refreshing, last updated (2021-09-29 15:37:37, 302511)
```

but then I run it again, and the first `select` query still shows old data. The view doesn't "stay" refreshed with the latest data:

```
LambdaRefreshView: Starting to refresh, last updated (2021-09-24 21:31:46, 299906)
LambdaRefreshView: Finished refreshing, last updated (2021-09-29 15:37:37, 302514)
```

I've different variations of the refresh command with/without `CONCURRENTLY` and `WITH DATA`, but it has no effect.

Any ideas? Python 3.6.14, psycopg2 2.9.1, PostgreSQL 9.6.22

If I run `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY my_view;` from psql, with the same DSN/user/password, it refreshes properly! And re-running from Lambda shows the updated data:

psql:

```
postgres=> select max(updated_at), count(*) from my_view;
              max              | count  
-------------------------------+--------
 2021-09-24 21:31:46.262262+00 | 299906
(1 row)

postgres=> REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY my_view;
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW
postgres=> select max(updated_at), count(*) from my_view;
              max              | count  
-------------------------------+--------
 2021-09-29 15:40:53.123746+00 | 302515
(1 row)
```

And the Lambda function sees this new, fresh, data:

```
LambdaRefreshView: Starting to refresh, last updated (2021-09-29 15:40:53, 302515)
LambdaRefreshView: Finished refreshing, last updated (2021-09-29 15:40:53, 302515)
```

Comment: Is the refresh performed in a transaction that doesn't get committed?

Comment: Thank you! Adding a `conn.commit()` fixed the issue. I didn't expect a transaction to be open while running this.